# Can JPA @PostUpdate listener callback method be executed asynchronously?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, post-update

I have a use-case where I need to execute some logic asynchronously, after my entity has been updated in database.

I am evaluating option to use JPA listener **@PostUpdate** method, which will be executed after my entity has been updated in database, but it seems that it blocks the main thread.

Can the logic inside of the @PostUpdate listener method be executed asynchronously?

Comment: Inside the @PostUpdate method you can do your logic in separate thread.

Comment: Yes, I assume that can be the only solution. I've even tried to execute Async method in another Spring component from PostUpdate method, but that doesn't work as well. Thanks @Saurabh